# Can't find .bashrc for Mac

Tags: macos, bash

I made a .bashrc file in my home directory, but to make the terminal read the file you have to type 'bash'. Can you fix this in some way?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your **default shell** to bash.

`chsh -s /bin/bash`

Or if you prefer GUI settings and always use the **Terminal App**, the option for default shell should be found in menu Terminal > Preferences > tab Startup. Choose "Shell opens with: Command" and type path `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute `.bashrc` automatically, you should be using `bash` as your shell.

[this link](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/) describes - How to Change Terminal Apps Default Shell in OS X

Once you'll set it to be `/bin/bash` `.bashrc` will be read/executed automatically.